# Access FTP URL with ftplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I am using python in Windows with ftplib to access a folder  at ftp5.xyz.eu.

The folder is 'baz' in  ftp5.xyz.eu in the folder 'foo bar'. So : ftp5.xyz.eu/foo bar/baz

I connect successfully at ftp5.xyz.eu but when i write the whole path to the folder it gives me an error:

```
from ftplib import FTP

#domain name or server ip:
ftp = FTP('ftp5.xyz.eu/foo%20bar')
...
ftp.dir()
```

error gived below:

```
  File "C:\Users\mirel.voicu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Users\mirel.voicu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\mirel.voicu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\mirel.voicu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the space. The first argument of [`FTP` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) is `host` – a *hostname* or an *IP address* – not an *URL*.

So it should be:

```
ftp = FTP('ftp5.xyz.eu')
```

---

If you want to list files in `foo bar` subfolder, either do:

```
ftp.cwd('foo bar')      
ftp.dir()
```

or

```
ftp.dir('foo bar')
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is Python's slightly obtuse way of saying "there is no server with that name"; and indeed, the server name here is not valid. You are passing `'ftp5.xyz.eu/foo%20bar'` where you should be passing in just `'ftp5.xyz.eu'`.

FTP traditionally does not use URL addresses, and Python's `ftplib` has no support for parsing them. You will need to pick apart the URL using, oh, I guess [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html), and take it from there.

```py
from ftplib import FTP
from urllib.parse import urlparse

parsed = urlparse('ftp://ftp5.xyz.eu/foo%20bar')
ftp = FTP(parsed.netloc)
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd(parsed.path)
ftp.dir()
```

The parsed `parsed.path` still uses `%20` where probably the FTP server expects a literal space; maybe also do URL decoding ([`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) or maybe [`urlllib.parse.unquote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus)).